# VSCode How to disable/remove "react/cjs/react.development" autocompletion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

As the title says, there is a `react/cjs/react.development` library that is sometimes added when auto completing normal React elements like `useState`.

I used to ignore it and select React, but it suddenly caused a very hard to track error in production.
**I want to delete/disable/remove it or atleast the autocompletion, how is this possible in VSCode**?

Comment: I guess you want to let the code suggests hidden?If so, you can remove the relative plugins which you don't need in vscode.

Comment: @taolu Not all, only this one in particular, it seems to come prepackaged from a controlled expo project. But in order to keep the question more general any non desired library (like .development ones), as I'm seeing the project depends on having it, but not my code specially for production.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution where I installed DefinitelyTyped react through @types/react package

`npm i @types/react`

update: I figured another solution without installing any packages through installing [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next)
 vscode extension.

Comment: FYI, This also works for JS react projects. Thanks, mate! This was annoying me as hell.

Comment: you're welcome body :)

Comment: JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly fixed the issue for me as well, thanks! =)

Comment: you're welcome Mutu :)