# Bad autocomplete in eslint-config-react-app: 'react/cjs/react.development'

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, create-react-app

#### Background

For a very simple ReactJS project, I wanted to
[add ESLint capabilities](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/eslint-config-react-app/README.md) :

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app eslint@^8.0.0
```

`package.json` after installing ESLint :

```json
{
  "name": "reactjs-app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above `package.json`, none of the three dependencies `next`,
`react`, `react-dom`, depends on any ESLint package – neither
directly nor indirectly.
So all installed ESLint packages are dependencies of
`eslint-config-react-app`.

---

All [the files needed for the project are in a zip file](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Q71819622.zip)
available for download.
To try it out, just download, unpack and run `npm install`.
<sup>1</sup>

`index.js` :

```js
// index.js
import { useState } from 'react';

function HomePage() {
  const [showParagraph, setShowParagraph] = useState(true);
  const showParagraphHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setShowParagraph((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
  }, []);
  console.log('App RUNNING');
  console.log(showParagraph);
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h1>Hi there!</h1>
      <button onClick={showParagraphHandler}>A button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HomePage;
```

### The question

An observant reader will notice that the import for `useCallback` is
missing.

But autocompletion (in VS Code <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>)
wrongly suggests to import from
`react/cjs/react.development`, *or* from
`react/cjs/react.production.min`,
instead of from `react` which would have been more correct.

#### *Why does this happen? – Is there a bug fix?*

[image: 'react/cjs/react.development' is suggested, not 'react'.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

### References

- [README for `eslint-config-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/eslint-config-react-app/README.md)
- [All the project files in a zip file](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Q71819622.zip)
- [Suggested solutions for the bug in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860430)

---

<sup>1</sup>
For me, the `npm install` command took about 5 minutes to complete.
The `npm install` command downloads and installs all packages in
`package.json` – including indirect packages.

Running `npm run dev` from the command line should start the
application in your default web browser.

Comment: `npm i -D @types/react`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why does this happen? – Is there a bug fix?*

It seems the reason is that `@types/react` is a missing dependency in
`eslint-config-react-app` so the obvious bug fix is to add
`@types/react` manually to your project by running :

```
npm install @types/react --save-dev
```

VS Code's autocompletion through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
now correctly suggests `react`.
<sup>1</sup>

[image: VS Code's autocompletion now correctly suggests 'react'.]

Installing `@types/react` adds `"@types/react": "^18.0.0",` in your
`package.json` under `"dependencies"` :

```json
{
  "name": "reactjs-app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "next": "^12.1.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
If it doesn't work, try restarting VS Code.

Comment: Great! `npm i -D @types/react`